Am I taking the right approach for powering a mains-powered radio with SSRs and a diode OR circuit?
I'm building a mains-powered radio that requires a 5V supply and have a few specific design requirements and constraints. I’d appreciate some feedback to confirm if I’m on the right track or if there are any improvements I could make - or should I approach this in a completely different way?

I want to switch the unit on and off from a power switch on the front panel, but when it comes to mains I have a “healthy respect” and don’t want to route AC mains to the front panel. I’m thinking of using two solid state relays (SSRs) to control both the incoming AC line and neutral. I’m thinking of using SSR 40DA as these handle the 240V mains and can be switched with a voltage down to 3V. The disadvantage is that they are rather bulky.
Any casing is grounded.
I’m using a Meanwell 5V switched power supply for the primary power source.
To keep the SSRs closed, I’d like to  implement a diode OR circuit to switch between a battery backup and the 5V rail.
I think I need  a 4.5V battery to cater for the diode drops (even with schottky diodes), but I'd prefer to reduce this to a 3V coin cell for compactness. Is there a way to do this, but still guarantee that the SSRs can be switched?

Circuit diagram is:

Is this approach feasible for reliable and safe operation, or are there alternative methods I should consider?

I don't see an issue with it working.  It is less than ideal to have a mains powered device still reliant on a battery for operation.

A data sheet for the SSR is likely required. I'm thinking that the input photodiode ought to have current limiting. Also, given that the Meanwell supply is so puny why are you choosing SSRs with such mega-high capacity?

@Aaron thanks for the taking a look. I've been assuming that the batteries would last a long time (they are only used to switch the SSRs). As the radio circuit uses an MCU I've also thought about using that to monitor the battery state so I could change them before they run out.

@Andy aka. I've never used SSRs before so was unaware that I may need to provide some current limiting. Thanks for pointing that out and I'll look into it. As to the "beefy" SSR, I've only considered using it as it seems to be widely available. I think I need to do some more research into more appropriately dimensioned SSRs.

@AndrewDoble I think you should also use reputable supplies and not Amazon or eBay. There are plenty of more realistic sized SSRs from the proper sources.

@AndrewDoble When AC is connected the battery should power the SSRs just long enough to turn them on, then it will switch over to the 5V supply and that will power them, but if AC is not connected the battery will supply them continuously, even though they won't be doing anything. You could use a DPDT ON-OFF-ON switch so that in one position PWR_ON goes to just the radio and in the other it goes to both the radio and SSRs, that would make your battery last longer at the expense of having a "Battery-Off-AC" power switch.

@Andy aka. Good point. Just been spending sometime looking at a large US distributor  at what they have. Haven't found anything yet (I really would like to have optical isolation), but early days yet.

@GodJihyo interesting idea. I'm going to have to explore that further.

Try digikey or mouser. These are worldwide electronic distributors with a decent reputation and reliable sources with tracking (I believe). There's also Newark (called Farnell in the UK). Maybe RS components has a presence in the states. Hope you voted in a way that helps world-wide democracy and peace @AndrewDoble <-- I won't hold it against you if you didn.t LOL

@Andy aka. Digikey was the one I was trying. As to your other point. I'm German and can't help you there ;-)
